# Why the error of a neural network gets lower in each training set but not in all of them at one time

Tags: neural-network

I am solving XOR problem. Every iteration goes correctly, but when i do the epochs and iteration cycles at one time the error does not get lower

Comment: Please put your code and ask your question

Comment: What do you mean at one time? The iterations are supposed to happen one after the other, not all at the same time. second iteration is based on the resulting error and weights of the first iteration.

Comment: Yes u are right. the code is here https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1009727/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BE